# Почему выдает ошибку The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST?

Tags: laravel

Мне выдает ошибку `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` на роуте, которвый использует post метод. Почему так происходит?

```
Route::post('/cart/add/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'add'])->where('id', '[1-9]+')->name('cart.add');
```

[image: get]

Comment: в смысле? у вас объявлен метод post `Route::post...` сами же ответили на свой вопрос

Comment: А пишет, что используется метод get

Comment: Ну так в скриншоте ниже написано что выполняется GET. Вас это не смущает?

Comment: @Vladimir естественно метод гет. А что по вашему выполняется когда вы переходите по ссылке в браузере, открывая любой сайт? перед тем как писать что-то изучите как работает http, что такое метод гет, пост, пут, делит и как их отправить в браузер. Ошибка же черным по белому говорит: "Метод ГЕТ не поддерживается на этом маршруте. Поддерживаются: POST"